# MouseListener and KeyListener used at the same time

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, mouselistener

How do I use MouseListener and KeyListener at the same time?

For example, how to do something like this

```
public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e){
// If the mouse button is clicked while any key is held down, print the key
}
```

Comment: *"How do I use MouseListener and KeyListener at the same time?"*  Why are you dealing with either?  Swing typically uses key bindings rather than the lower level `KeyListener`, and an `ActionListener` will sometimes be a better alternative to a `MouseListener`.  What is all this intended to support?

Answer (score 2):

Use a boolean value for whether a mouse button is held down, and then update that variable in a MouseListener.

```
boolean buttonDown = false;

public class ExampleListener implements MouseListener {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        buttonDown = true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        buttonDown = false;
    }

    //Other implemented methods unimportant to this post... 
}
```

Then, in your KeyListener class, just test the buttonDown variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a boolean `isKeyPressed`. In `keyPressed`, set it to true and in `keyReleased` set it to false. Then, when the mouse is clicked, first check if isKeyPressed is true.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking the state of the `KeyEvent` modifiers, for example...

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int mods = e.getModifiers();
        System.out.println(mods);
        if ((mods & KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0) {
            System.out.println("Button1 down");
        }
    }
});
```

I should also point out, you can do...

```
int ext = e.getModifiersEx();
if ((ext & KeyEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
    System.out.println("Button1_down_mask");
}
```

Which, as I've just discovered, produces results for other mouse buttons...

Comment: :O could you explain me your code if you have time why that bitwise should be != 0.. btw should be `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK`?

Comment: @nachokk No, I tried `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK`, but Java insists on using the out-dated `BUTTON1_DOWN`

Comment: and `mods & KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK != 0` what it means?

Comment: @nachokk My bitwise maths is...crap...however...basically, as I understand it, it is trying to extract the value of `BUTTON1_MASK` from the modifiers so that it will either return 16 or 0 (16 when `BUTTON1_MASK` has been or'ed in)...I don't know why, I just copy and paste ;)